# How can I, when hovering over a link, have the background color span the whole of the frame it is in?

Tags: html, css, iframe, colors, background

Basically, I am using Iframes on my website, and I have a 200px bar on the left which I am using for navigation. There are several links here, of which when I hover over them the text and background colors invert (so you can see it, basically).

What I want is that so the background color will span the whole of the navigation frame - currently, it is only a small square around the box. I want it to look like this at any resolution and so far... my attempts have been useless.

I am using HTML and CSS, and would preferably like a solution using those languages.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please post some code, a link, or a jsFiddle.

Comment: How about using display:block on the anchor link?

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly sure this can't be done without the use of JavaScript.  Consider the code at

http://jsfiddle.net/ZPzBL/

the `a:hover` only allows the style of the link to be changed.

If you want the whole `div` to change colour (which, if I've read your question correctly, is what you want), then using purely html, you'd need to have a style with `.wrapper:hover`, such as this:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZPzBL/1/,

but this means that the whole div changes colour as soon as you hover over it.

Essentially, CSS only lets you change the style of the element being hovered over at that time.  Any other changes to the DOM need to be handled by JavaScript.  You'll probably want to have a look at http://api.jquery.com/hover/